How to completely change the `f` key to a `/` and the `F` key to a `?`
I use neovim latest version 0.10.1, I want to convert the entire function of f button to / button and F button to ?, because I often use / and ? function to search for more than just f and F, I installed the following
local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
local keymap = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap
keymap('n', '/', 'f', opts)
keymap('n', 'f', '/', opts)
keymap('n', 'F', '?', opts)
keymap('n', '?', 'F', opts)

However, if I simply press f and F it works as expected, but when I press df and dF to delete, it still returns to the original function without becoming d/ and d?. How to completely replace, even when combined with key combinations. Thank you very much!

You should also add these mappings in Operator-pending mode to have df etc. commands work as expected. You probably also want these in Visual mode, so that f and / etc. work the same way when you're in visual mode. See :help :map-modes for more details on the modes.
Using nvim_set_keymap you can set these three mappings with a single command by using an empty string as the mode (similar to the Vim :noremap command), with the caveat that this also affects Select mode which is probably not what you want, as Select mode is more like Insert mode where f or / would insert those characters.
So more appropriate would be to use the 'n', 'o' and 'x' modes.
To do so using nvim_set_keymap would require calling it three separate times.
Modern NeoVim has a new API vim.keymap.set which allows passing a table with the modes you want to set. Not only that, it also defaults to using "noremap" which is typically what you want.
So these should work for you:
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'o', 'x'}, '/', 'f', { silent = true })
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'o', 'x'}, 'f', '/', { silent = true })
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'o', 'x'}, '?', 'F', { silent = true })
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'o', 'x'}, 'F', '?', { silent = true })


:nunmap can also be used outside of a monastery. https://neovim.io/doc/user/map.html#map-overview

@Rmano Do you mean :sunmap to undo the Select-mode mappings?

no,sorry, I was just reading the doc following your link and found the joke too fun not to point to it... So really a non-sequitur.
